# React-router v4 - display current page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a main component, `App` that holds all my `Match` components. I'd like to be able to display the current page at the top (in header, for example) but I'm having trouble getting the current pathname.

In `App` I have:

```
App.contextTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

And I pass the current path name to a component:

```
<Header currentPathname={this.context.history.location.pathname} />
```

However, `App` doesn't seem to update when the location changes. How can I listen for this and pass as a prop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you want your header to show on all routes, if you're putting it above your `Match` components. In that case, also use `Match` for your header, and match on every pattern and you will have access to `location` through `props`.

```
<Match 
  pattern="/" 
  component={props => <Header pathname={props.location.pathname} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Match` is not a component anymore in react-router-dom (^4.3.1). Instead, I did this:

`<Route path="" component={(props) => <Header {...props} page={"Main Page"} />}/>`

In Header.js:

```
const Header = (props) => (
  <header className="App-header">
  { console.log(props) }
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
    <TitleDiv>App Name : {props.page}</TitleDiv>
  </header>
);
```

The result is `App Name : Main Page`